# Most efficient conversion of ResultSet to JSON?

Tags: java, sql, json, resultset

The following code converts a `ResultSet` to a JSON string using [`JSONArray`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) and [`JSONObject`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html).

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;

public class ResultSetConverter {
  public static JSONArray convert( ResultSet rs )
    throws SQLException, JSONException
  {
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

    while(rs.next()) {
      int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

      for (int i=1; i<numColumns+1; i++) {
        String column_name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);

        if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.ARRAY){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getArray(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.BIGINT){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getBoolean(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.BLOB){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getBlob(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.DOUBLE){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getDouble(column_name)); 
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.FLOAT){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getFloat(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.INTEGER){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getNString(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.VARCHAR){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getString(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.TINYINT){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.SMALLINT){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.DATE){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getDate(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP){
        obj.put(column_name, rs.getTimestamp(column_name));   
        }
        else{
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getObject(column_name));
        }
      }

      json.put(obj);
    }

    return json;
  }
}
```

- Is there a faster way?
- Is there a way that uses less memory?

Comment: A different implementation http://code.google.com/p/bonex-homerunning/source/browse/trunk/+bonex-homerunning/WEB-INF/src/java/com/bonex/sys/util/JSONUtil.java?spec=svn18&r=18

Comment: implementation for java.sql.Types.ARRAY didn't work for me using postgresql (array got put as a String using "{...}". Ended up changing line
  "obj.put(column_name, rs.getArray(column_name));"
to
  "Array array = rs.getArray(column_name);
  if ( array != null ) obj.put(column_name, new JSONArray(array.getArray()));"

Comment: If performance is a major issue, you shouldn't use this JSON API but rather use a streaming library that just writes JSON without needing to create memory objects of all the data (where you can look back/find stuff in the tree). That said, I would make sure you actually have a performance issue before doing that.

Comment: There are an error in your snippet. `java.sql.Types.BIGINT` is 8 bytes size, so it must be read with `rs.getLong()` not `rs.getInt()`

Comment: I think all the `if` `else if` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The JIT Compiler is probably going to make this pretty fast since it's just branches and basic tests. You could probably make it more elegant with a HashMap lookup to a callback but I doubt it would be any faster. As to memory, this is pretty slim as is.

Somehow I doubt this code is actually a critical bottle neck for memory or performance. Do you have any real reason to try to optimize it?

Comment: I'm putting the source code in an open-source framework, so I do not know what it will be used for. Therefore I am trying to make it as efficient as possible.

Comment: @DevinDixon: is the framework available?  Is there anything like the code in your question already available in an open source repo somewhere?

Comment: Please provide example.

Answer (score 40):

I think there's a way to use less memory (a fixed and not linear amount depending on data cardinality) but this imply to change the method signature. In fact we may print the Json data directly on an output stream as soon as we fetch them from the ResultSet: the already written data will be garbage collected since we don't need an array that keeps them in memory.

I use GSON that accepts type adapters. I wrote a type adapter to convert ResultSet to JsonArray and it looks very like to your code. I'm waiting the "Gson 2.1: Targeted Dec 31, 2011" release which will have the "Support for user-defined streaming type adapters". Then I'll modify my adapter to be a streaming adapter.

---

### Update

As promised I'm back but not with Gson, instead with Jackson 2. Sorry to be late (of 2 years).

**Preface:** The key to use less memory of the result itsef is in the "server side" cursor. With this kind of cursors (a.k.a. resultset to Java devs) the DBMS sends data incrementally to client (a.k.a. driver) as the client goes forward with the reading. I think Oracle cursor are server side by default. For MySQL > 5.0.2 look for useCursorFetch at [connection url paramenter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html). Check about your favourite DBMS.

**1:** So to use less memory we must:

- use server side cursor behind the scene
- use resultset open as [read only](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#CONCUR_READ_ONLY) and, of course, [forward only](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY);
- avoid to load all the cursor in a list (or a `JSONArray`) but write each row directly on an *output line*, where for output line I mean an output stream or a writer or also a json generator that wraps an output stream or a writer.

**2:** As Jackson Documentation says:

> Streaming API is best performing (lowest overhead, fastest read/write;
> other 2 methods build on it)

**3:** I see you in your code use getInt, getBoolean. getFloat... of ResultSet without [wasNull](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull%28%29). I expect this can yield problems.

**4:** I used arrays to cache thinks and to avoid to call getters each iteration. Although not a fan of the switch/case construct, I used it for that `int` SQL `Types`.

**The answer:** Not yet fully tested, it's based on [Jackson 2.2](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The `ResultSetSerializer` object instructs Jackson on how to serialize (tranform the object to JSON) a ResultSet. It uses the Jackson Streaming API inside. Here the code of a test:

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(new ResultSetSerializer());

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(module);

[ . . . do the query . . . ]
ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);

// Use the DataBind Api here
ObjectNode objectNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();

// put the resultset in a containing structure
objectNode.putPOJO("results", resultset);

// generate all
objectMapper.writeValue(stringWriter, objectNode);
```

And, of course, the code of the ResultSetSerializer class:

```
public class ResultSetSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ResultSet> {

    public static class ResultSetSerializerException extends JsonProcessingException{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -914957626413580734L;

        public ResultSetSerializerException(Throwable cause){
            super(cause);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class<ResultSet> handledType() {
        return ResultSet.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(ResultSet rs, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        try {
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            String[] columnNames = new String[numColumns];
            int[] columnTypes = new int[numColumns];

            for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {
                columnNames[i] = rsmd.getColumnLabel(i + 1);
                columnTypes[i] = rsmd.getColumnType(i + 1);
            }

            jgen.writeStartArray();

            while (rs.next()) {
            
                boolean b;
                long l;
                double d;
            
                jgen.writeStartObject();
    
                for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {
    
                    jgen.writeFieldName(columnNames[i]);
                    switch (columnTypes[i]) {
    
                    case Types.INTEGER:
                        l = rs.getInt(i + 1);
                        if (rs.wasNull()) {
                            jgen.writeNull();
                        } else {
                            jgen.writeNumber(l);
                        }
                        break;
    
                    case Types.BIGINT:
                        l = rs.getLong(i + 1);
                        if (rs.wasNull()) {
                            jgen.writeNull();
                        } else {
                            jgen.writeNumber(l);
                        }
                        break;
    
                    case Types.DECIMAL:
                    case Types.NUMERIC:
                        jgen.writeNumber(rs.getBigDecimal(i + 1));
                        break;
    
                    case Types.FLOAT:
                    case Types.REAL:
                    case Types.DOUBLE:
                        d = rs.getDouble(i + 1);
                        if (rs.wasNull()) {
                            jgen.writeNull();
                        } else {
                            jgen.writeNumber(d);
                        }
                        break;
    
                    case Types.NVARCHAR:
                    case Types.VARCHAR:
                    case Types.LONGNVARCHAR:
                    case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
                        jgen.writeString(rs.getString(i + 1));
                        break;
    
                    case Types.BOOLEAN:
                    case Types.BIT:
                        b = rs.getBoolean(i + 1);
                        if (rs.wasNull()) {
                            jgen.writeNull();
                        } else {
                            jgen.writeBoolean(b);
                        }
                        break;
    
                    case Types.BINARY:
                    case Types.VARBINARY:
                    case Types.LONGVARBINARY:
                        jgen.writeBinary(rs.getBytes(i + 1));
                        break;
    
                    case Types.TINYINT:
                    case Types.SMALLINT:
                        l = rs.getShort(i + 1);
                        if (rs.wasNull()) {
                            jgen.writeNull();
                        } else {
                            jgen.writeNumber(l);
                        }
                        break;
    
                    case Types.DATE:
                        provider.defaultSerializeDateValue(rs.getDate(i + 1), jgen);
                        break;
    
                    case Types.TIMESTAMP:
                        provider.defaultSerializeDateValue(rs.getTimestamp(i + 1), jgen);
                        break;
    
                    case Types.BLOB:
                        Blob blob = rs.getBlob(i);
                        provider.defaultSerializeValue(blob.getBinaryStream(), jgen);
                        blob.free();
                        break;
    
                    case Types.CLOB:
                        Clob clob = rs.getClob(i);
                        provider.defaultSerializeValue(clob.getCharacterStream(), jgen);
                        clob.free();
                        break;
    
                    case Types.ARRAY:
                        throw new RuntimeException("ResultSetSerializer not yet implemented for SQL type ARRAY");
    
                    case Types.STRUCT:
                        throw new RuntimeException("ResultSetSerializer not yet implemented for SQL type STRUCT");
    
                    case Types.DISTINCT:
                        throw new RuntimeException("ResultSetSerializer not yet implemented for SQL type DISTINCT");
    
                    case Types.REF:
                        throw new RuntimeException("ResultSetSerializer not yet implemented for SQL type REF");

                    case Types.JAVA_OBJECT:
                    default:
                        provider.defaultSerializeValue(rs.getObject(i + 1), jgen);
                        break;
                    }
                }
    
                jgen.writeEndObject();
            }

            jgen.writeEndArray();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ResultSetSerializerException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a quick note:
In ```Types.TIMESTAMP```, it should be 
 ```provider.defaultSerializeDateValue(rs.getTimestamp(i + 1), jgen);```

Answer (score 37):

A simpler solution (based on code in question):

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
while(rs.next()) {
  int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
  for (int i=1; i<=numColumns; i++) {
    String column_name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
    obj.put(column_name, rs.getObject(column_name));
  }
  json.put(obj);
}
return json;
```

Comment: nice, but there is a bug with DATETIME and TIMESTAMP (it does not add Apostrophes

Comment: nice and simple

Answer (score 27):

Two things that will make this faster are:

Move your call to `rsmd.getColumnCount()` out of the while loop. The column count should not vary across rows.

For each column type, you end up calling something like this:

```
obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));
```

It will be slightly faster to use the column index to retrieve the column value:

```
obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(i));
```

Comment: Also define `String column_name;` out of the while loop.

Answer (score 11):

#### Use a third party library for the JSON export

You could use [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) for the job. You don't have to use all of jOOQ's features to take advantage of some useful JDBC extensions. In this case, simply write:

```
String json = DSL.using(connection).fetch(resultSet).formatJSON();
```

Relevant API methods used are:

- [`DSLContext.fetch(ResultSet)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#fetch%28java.sql.ResultSet%29) to convert a JDBC ResultSet into a jOOQ Result.
- [`Result.formatJSON()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html#formatJSON%28%29) to format the jOOQ Result into a JSON String.

The resulting formatting will look like this:

```javascript
{"fields":[{"name":"field-1","type":"type-1"},
           {"name":"field-2","type":"type-2"},
           ...,
           {"name":"field-n","type":"type-n"}],
 "records":[[value-1-1,value-1-2,...,value-1-n],
            [value-2-1,value-2-2,...,value-2-n]]}
```

You could also create your own formatting rather easily, through [`Result.map(RecordMapper)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html#map%28org.jooq.RecordMapper%29)

This essentially does the same as your code, circumventing the generation of JSON objects, "streaming" directly into a `StringBuilder`. I'd say that the performance overhead should be negligible in both cases, though.

(Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ)

#### Use SQL/JSON features instead

Of course, [you don't have to use your middleware to map JDBC ResultSets to JSON](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/11/13/stop-mapping-stuff-in-your-middleware-use-sqls-xml-or-json-operators-instead/). The question doesn't mention for which SQL dialect this needs to be done, but many support standard SQL/JSON syntax, or something similar, e.g.

**Oracle**

```sql
SELECT json_arrayagg(json_object(*))
FROM t
```

**SQL Server**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t
FOR JSON AUTO
```

**PostgreSQL**

```sql
SELECT to_jsonb(array_agg(t))
FROM t
```

Comment: This is awesome but I'm having troubles in parsing the resulting string. When some of the values contain a quotation mark the parser can't correctly work: I think that quotation marks inside values should be escaped (`"` to `\"`) in order to create a valid JSON string. Is this a bug of the `formatJSON()` function? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Oneiros: jOOQ should correctly escape those quotation marks... Best ask a new question (with details) or report a bug: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new

Comment: In your example, what is resultSet used in `fetch(resultSet)`? It's not defined anywhere. And if I get JDBC `ResultSet` before fetch what is the purpose of `DSL.using(connection)`? Why does it need connection? :)

Comment: @NikolaLošić: Well, the question asks about using a JDBC `ResultSet`, so I think there is no doubt about `ResultSet`. Indeed, it doesn't look obvious why the `connection` is needed here. If you're using jOOQ, you will have a `DSLContext` (the result of `DSL.using(connection)` or similar) sitting around available to you anyway, though.

Comment: what's the correct JOOQ library to include? I'm trying many but every one gives me Class not found error with  DSL reference. Thnks

Comment: @LorenzoBarbagli: Would you mind asking a new question with some details? There are many (possibly not jOOQ related) things that can go wrong...

Answer (score 7):

In addition to suggestions made by @Jim Cook. One other thought is to use a switch instead of if-elses:

```
while(rs.next()) {
  int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

  for( int i=1; i<numColumns+1; i++) {
    String column_name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);

    switch( rsmd.getColumnType( i ) ) {
      case java.sql.Types.ARRAY:
        obj.put(column_name, rs.getArray(column_name));     break;
      case java.sql.Types.BIGINT:
        obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));       break;
      case java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN:
        obj.put(column_name, rs.getBoolean(column_name));   break;
      case java.sql.Types.BLOB:
        obj.put(column_name, rs.getBlob(column_name));      break;
      case java.sql.Types.DOUBLE:
        obj.put(column_name, rs.getDouble(column_name));    break;
      case java.sql.Types.FLOAT:
        obj.put(column_name, rs.getFloat(column_name));     break;
      case java.sql.Types.INTEGER:
        obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));       break;
      case java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR:
        obj.put(column_name, rs.getNString(column_name));   break;
      case java.sql.Types.VARCHAR:
        obj.put(column_name, rs.getString(column_name));    break;
      case java.sql.Types.TINYINT:
        obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));       break;
      case java.sql.Types.SMALLINT:
        obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));       break;
      case java.sql.Types.DATE:
        obj.put(column_name, rs.getDate(column_name));      break;
      case java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP:
        obj.put(column_name, rs.getTimestamp(column_name)); break;
      default:
        obj.put(column_name, rs.getObject(column_name));    break;
    }
  }

  json.put(obj);
}
```

Comment: Looping backwards (comparing the index zero) is also faster (than comparing the index to an expression).

Answer (score 4):

This answer may not be the most efficient, but it sure is dynamic. Pairing native JDBC with Google's Gson library, I easily can convert from an SQL result to a JSON stream.

I have included the converter, example DB properties file, SQL table generation, and a Gradle build file (with dependencies used).

### QueryApp.java

```java
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import com.oracle.jdbc.ResultSetConverter;

public class QueryApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        String dbProps = "/database.properties";
        String indent = "    ";

        writer.println("Basic SELECT:");
        ResultSetConverter.queryToJson(writer, dbProps, "SELECT * FROM Beatles", indent, false);

        writer.println("\n\nIntermediate SELECT:");
        ResultSetConverter.queryToJson(writer, dbProps, "SELECT first_name, last_name, getAge(date_of_birth) as age FROM Beatles", indent, true);
    }
}
```

### ResultSetConverter.java

```java
package com.oracle.jdbc;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

public class ResultSetConverter {
    public static final Type RESULT_TYPE = new TypeToken<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3467016635635320150L;
    }.getType();

    public static void queryToJson(Writer writer, String connectionProperties, String query, String indent, boolean closeWriter) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
        JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(writer);

        if (indent != null) jsonWriter.setIndent(indent);

        try {
            Properties props = readConnectionInfo(connectionProperties);
            Class.forName(props.getProperty("driver"));

            conn = openConnection(props);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            gson.create().toJson(QueryHelper.select(stmt, query), RESULT_TYPE, jsonWriter);

            if (closeWriter) jsonWriter.close();

            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                if (stmt != null) stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException se2) {
            }
            try {
                if (conn != null) conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                if (closeWriter && jsonWriter != null) jsonWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static Properties readConnectionInfo(String resource) throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        InputStream in = ResultSetConverter.class.getResourceAsStream(resource);
        properties.load(in);
        in.close();

        return properties;
    }

    private static Connection openConnection(Properties connectionProperties) throws IOException, SQLException {
        String database = connectionProperties.getProperty("database");
        String username = connectionProperties.getProperty("username");
        String password = connectionProperties.getProperty("password");

        return DriverManager.getConnection(database, username, password);
    }
}
```

### QueryHelper.java

```java
package com.oracle.jdbc;

import java.sql.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

import com.google.common.base.CaseFormat;

public class QueryHelper {
    static DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> select(Statement stmt, String query) throws SQLException {
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        List<Map<String, Object>> records = mapRecords(resultSet);

        resultSet.close();

        return records;
    }

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> mapRecords(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        List<Map<String, Object>> records = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            records.add(mapRecord(resultSet, metaData));
        }

        return records;
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> mapRecord(ResultSet resultSet, ResultSetMetaData metaData) throws SQLException {
        Map<String, Object> record = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        for (int c = 1; c <= metaData.getColumnCount(); c++) {
            String columnType = metaData.getColumnTypeName(c);
            String columnName = formatPropertyName(metaData.getColumnName(c));
            Object value = resultSet.getObject(c);

            if (columnType.equals("DATE")) {
                value = DATE_FORMAT.format(value);
            }

            record.put(columnName, value);
        }

        return record;
    }

    private static String formatPropertyName(String property) {
        return CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL, property);
    }
}
```

### database.properties

```sh
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database=jdbc:mysql://localhost/JDBC_Tutorial
username=root
password=
```

### JDBC_Tutorial.sql

```sql
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Jan 12, 2016 at 07:40 PM
-- Server version: 10.1.8-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 5.6.14

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `jdbc_tutorial`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `jdbc_tutorial` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `jdbc_tutorial`;

DELIMITER $$
--
-- Functions
--
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `getAge`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getAge` (`in_dob` DATE) RETURNS INT(11) NO SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE l_age INT;
   IF DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'00-%m-%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(in_dob,'00-%m-%d') THEN
      -- This person has had a birthday this year
      SET l_age=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y')-DATE_FORMAT(in_dob,'%Y');
   ELSE
      -- Yet to have a birthday this year
      SET l_age=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y')-DATE_FORMAT(in_dob,'%Y')-1;
   END IF;
      RETURN(l_age);
END$$

DELIMITER ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `beatles`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `beatles`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `beatles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Truncate table before insert `beatles`
--

TRUNCATE TABLE `beatles`;
--
-- Dumping data for table `beatles`
--

INSERT INTO `beatles` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `date_of_birth`) VALUES(100, 'John', 'Lennon', '1940-10-09');
INSERT INTO `beatles` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `date_of_birth`) VALUES(101, 'Paul', 'McCartney', '1942-06-18');
INSERT INTO `beatles` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `date_of_birth`) VALUES(102, 'George', 'Harrison', '1943-02-25');
INSERT INTO `beatles` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `date_of_birth`) VALUES(103, 'Ringo', 'Starr', '1940-07-07');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

### build.gradle

```groovy
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'com.oracle.jdbc.QueryApp'

repositories {
    maven  {
        url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
    }
}

jar {
    baseName = 'jdbc-tutorial'
    version =  '1.0.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

dependencies {
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.2'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.9'
}
```

---

## Results

#### Basic SELECT

```javascript
[
    {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Lennon",
        "dateOfBirth": "1940-10-09",
        "id": 100
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Paul",
        "lastName": "McCartney",
        "dateOfBirth": "1942-06-18",
        "id": 101
    },
    {
        "firstName": "George",
        "lastName": "Harrison",
        "dateOfBirth": "1943-02-25",
        "id": 102
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Ringo",
        "lastName": "Starr",
        "dateOfBirth": "1940-07-07",
        "id": 103
    }
]
```

#### Intermediate SELECT

```javascript
[
    {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Lennon",
        "age": 75
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Paul",
        "lastName": "McCartney",
        "age": 73
    },
    {
        "firstName": "George",
        "lastName": "Harrison",
        "age": 72
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Ringo",
        "lastName": "Starr",
        "age": 75
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

First pre-generate column names, second use `rs.getString(i)` instead of `rs.getString(column_name)`.

The following is an implementation of this:

```
    /*
     * Convert ResultSet to a common JSON Object array
     * Result is like: [{"ID":"1","NAME":"Tom","AGE":"24"}, {"ID":"2","NAME":"Bob","AGE":"26"}, ...]
     */
    public static List<JSONObject> getFormattedResult(ResultSet rs) {
        List<JSONObject> resList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        try {
            // get column names
            ResultSetMetaData rsMeta = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnCnt = rsMeta.getColumnCount();
            List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i=1;i<=columnCnt;i++) {
                columnNames.add(rsMeta.getColumnName(i).toUpperCase());
            }

            while(rs.next()) { // convert each object to an human readable JSON object
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                for(int i=1;i<=columnCnt;i++) {
                    String key = columnNames.get(i - 1);
                    String value = rs.getString(i);
                    obj.put(key, value);
                }
                resList.add(obj);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return resList;
    }
```

Comment: how do i access and use the object ....say i want to print the whole Name column..and is the object easily available for CRUD operations??

Comment: @Prathameshdhanawade This method is to covert JDBC ResultSet to a JSON array. Developers usually do not use raw JDBC ResultSet, they usually convert it to a list of Java objects, i.e. JSON object. You see the return value is an array of JSON objects. You are easily access one object through `JSONObject json = resList.get(i);` Then you are free to manipulate the JSON object `json`.

Comment: Actually i will be needing the object to prepare a graphical view. So i ws just curious i could manipulate the object. Thnx.

Comment: Could you please describe "graphical view"? Or given an example?

Comment: I am trying to display column value as :


JSONObject obj= jsonList.get(1);
          
          System.out.println(obj.getString("name")+"\t"+obj.getString("company"));

but getting an error as " org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["name"] not found."

Comment: @Prathameshdhanawade That means key "name" does not exist. I suggest you `System.out.println(obj);` (or use debug mode) to see which keys the JSON object have.

Comment: I did. Nd found out to be casing issue. I m good now and can manipulate the object at my will.

Comment: @Prathameshdhanawade Glad to hear that:)

Answer (score 2):

Just as a heads up, the if/then loop is more efficient than the switch for enums.  If you have the switch against the raw enum integer, then it's more efficient, but against the variable, if/then is more efficient, at least for Java 5, 6, and 7.

I.e., for some reason (after some performance tests)

```
if (ordinalValue == 1) {
   ...
} else (ordinalValue == 2 {
   ... 
}
```

is faster than

```
switch( myEnum.ordinal() ) {
    case 1:
       ...
       break;
    case 2:
       ...
       break;
}
```

I see that a few people are doubting me, so I'll post code here that you can run yourself to see the difference, along with output I have from Java 7.  The results of the following code with 10 enum values are as follows.  Note the key here is the if/then using an integer value comparing against ordinal constants of the enum, vs. the switch with an enum's ordinal value against the raw int ordinal values, vs. a switch with the enum against each enum name.  The if/then with an integer value beat out both other switches, although the last switch was a little faster than the first switch, it was not faster than the if/else.

If / else took 23 ms
Switch took 45 ms
Switch 2 took 30 ms
Total matches: 3000000

```
package testing;

import java.util.Random;

enum TestEnum {
    FIRST,
    SECOND,
    THIRD,
    FOURTH,
    FIFTH,
    SIXTH,
    SEVENTH,
    EIGHTH,
    NINTH,
    TENTH
}

public class SwitchTest {
    private static int LOOP = 1000000;
    private static Random r = new Random();
    private static int SIZE = TestEnum.values().length;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int matches = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++) {
            int j = r.nextInt(SIZE);
            if (j == TestEnum.FIRST.ordinal()) {
                matches++;
            } else if (j == TestEnum.SECOND.ordinal()) {
                matches++;
            } else if (j == TestEnum.THIRD.ordinal()) {
                matches++;
            } else if (j == TestEnum.FOURTH.ordinal()) {
                matches++;
            } else if (j == TestEnum.FIFTH.ordinal()) {
                matches++;
            } else if (j == TestEnum.SIXTH.ordinal()) {
                matches++;
            } else if (j == TestEnum.SEVENTH.ordinal()) {
                matches++;
            } else if (j == TestEnum.EIGHTH.ordinal()) {
                matches++;
            } else if (j == TestEnum.NINTH.ordinal()) {
                matches++;
            } else {
                matches++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("If / else took "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - time)+" ms");
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++) {
            TestEnum te = TestEnum.values()[r.nextInt(SIZE)];
            switch (te.ordinal()) {
                case 0:
                    matches++;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    matches++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    matches++;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    matches++;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    matches++;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    matches++;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    matches++;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    matches++;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    matches++;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    matches++;
                    break;
                default:
                    matches++;
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Switch took "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - time)+" ms");
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++) {
            TestEnum te = TestEnum.values()[r.nextInt(SIZE)];
            switch (te) {
                case FIRST:
                    matches++;
                    break;
                case SECOND:
                    matches++;
                    break;
                case THIRD:
                    matches++;
                    break;
                case FOURTH:
                    matches++;
                    break;
                case FIFTH:
                    matches++;
                    break;
                case SIXTH:
                    matches++;
                    break;
                case SEVENTH:
                    matches++;
                    break;
                case EIGHTH:
                    matches++;
                    break;
                case NINTH:
                    matches++;
                    break;
                default:
                    matches++;
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Switch 2 took "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - time)+" ms");     
        System.out.println("Total matches: "+matches);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, ok but .. the practical truth is that the difference between these coding alternatives for any real use case is so small that, in a real application, the performance differences among them would most likely be immeasurably small.  Make your code correct first and then (only then) make it fast (if it needs to be faster).

Comment: Agreed, but the main question was in regards to the fastest, most efficient way.  There are many styles that make code difficult to read or maintain, but are more efficient, although typically these are resolved by compiler optimizations at some point in the future.  One example of this is the use of `intern()` for strings which are largely no longer needed in most modern versions of Java.

Comment: Agreed, but if-then-else and switch-case blocks themselves are poor solutions for problems of maintainability, robustness, and readability in any case.  For enums that you own (or whose code you can modify), the best practice is very often to use constant-specific methods in a rich enum type,  Most of the time, switching on an enum should be viewed with circumspection because there are better solutions out there.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone plan to use this implementation, You might wanna [check this out](http://www.cs.mun.ca/~michael/java/jdk1.1-beta2-docs/guide/jdbc/mapping.doc.html) [and this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html)

This is my version of that convertion code:

```
public class ResultSetConverter {
public static JSONArray convert(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
        JSONException {
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    while (rs.next()) {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

        for (int i = 1; i < numColumns + 1; i++) {
            String column_name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);

            if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.ARRAY) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getArray(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.BIGINT) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getLong(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.REAL) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getFloat(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getBoolean(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.BLOB) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getBlob(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.DOUBLE) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getDouble(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.FLOAT) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getDouble(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.INTEGER) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getNString(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.VARCHAR) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getString(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.CHAR) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getString(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.NCHAR) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getNString(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.LONGNVARCHAR) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getNString(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.LONGVARCHAR) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getString(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.TINYINT) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getByte(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.SMALLINT) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getShort(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.DATE) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getDate(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.TIME) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getTime(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getTimestamp(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.BINARY) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getBytes(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.VARBINARY) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getBytes(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.LONGVARBINARY) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getBinaryStream(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.BIT) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getBoolean(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.CLOB) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getClob(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.NUMERIC) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getBigDecimal(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.DECIMAL) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getBigDecimal(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.DATALINK) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getURL(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.REF) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getRef(column_name));
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.STRUCT) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getObject(column_name)); // must be a custom mapping consists of a class that implements the interface SQLData and an entry in a java.util.Map object.
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.DISTINCT) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getObject(column_name)); // must be a custom mapping consists of a class that implements the interface SQLData and an entry in a java.util.Map object.
            } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.JAVA_OBJECT) {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getObject(column_name));
            } else {
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getString(i));
            }
        }

        json.put(obj);
    }

    return json;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static JSONArray GetJSONDataFromResultSet(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
    int count = metaData.getColumnCount();
    String[] columnName = new String[count];
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    while(rs.next()) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++){
               columnName[i-1] = metaData.getColumnLabel(i);
               jsonObject.put(columnName[i-1], rs.getObject(i));
        }
        jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For all who've opted for the if-else mesh solution, please use:

```
String columnName = metadata.getColumnName(
String displayName = metadata.getColumnLabel(i);
switch (metadata.getColumnType(i)) {
case Types.ARRAY:
    obj.put(displayName, resultSet.getArray(columnName));
    break;
...
```

Because in case of aliases in your query, the column name and column label are two different things. For example if you execute:

```
select col1, col2 as my_alias from table
```

You will get

```
[
    { "col1": 1, "col2": 2 }, 
    { "col1": 1, "col2": 2 }
]
```

Rather than:

```
[
    { "col1": 1, "my_alias": 2 }, 
    { "col1": 1, "my_alias": 2 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.idal.cib;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class DBJsonConverter {

    static ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    static Connection conn = null;
    static PreparedStatement ps = null;
    static ResultSet rs = null;
    static String path = "";
    static String driver="";
    static String url="";
    static String username="";
    static String password="";
    static String query="";

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    public static void dataLoad(String path) {
        JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        conn = DatabaseConnector.getDbConnection(driver, url, username,
                password);
        try {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            ArrayList<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (rs != null) {
                ResultSetMetaData columns = rs.getMetaData();
                int i = 0;
                while (i < columns.getColumnCount()) {
                    i++;
                    columnNames.add(columns.getColumnName(i));
                }
                while (rs.next()) {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                    for (i = 0; i < columnNames.size(); i++) {
                        data.add(rs.getString(columnNames.get(i)));
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < data.size(); j++) {
                                if (data.get(j) != null) {
                                    obj.put(columnNames.get(i), data.get(j));
                                }else {
                                    obj.put(columnNames.get(i), "");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    jsonArray.add(obj);
                    obj1.put("header", jsonArray);
                    FileWriter file = new FileWriter(path);
                    file.write(obj1.toJSONString());
                    file.flush();
                    file.close();
                }
                ps.close();
            } else {
                JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
                obj2.put(null, null);
                jsonArray.add(obj2);
                obj1.put("header", jsonArray);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                    rs.close();
                    ps.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:database";
        username = "user";
        password = "password";
        path = "path of file";
        query = "select * from temp_employee";

        DatabaseConnector dc = new DatabaseConnector();
        dc.getDbConnection(driver,url,username,password);
        DBJsonConverter formatter = new DBJsonConverter();
        formatter.dataLoad(path);

    }

}




package com.idal.cib;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DatabaseConnector {

    static Connection conn1 = null;

    public static Connection getDbConnection(String driver, String url,
            String username, String password) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        try {

            Class.forName(driver);

            conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Pl add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work without any explicit type check. Utilize Java types and ObjectMapper to infer the types and create JSON values internally.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNodeFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public JsonNode getData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ArrayNode jsonArr = JsonNodeFactory.instance.arrayNode();
        while(rs.next()) {
            int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            ObjectNode rowNode = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
            IntStream.range(1, columnCount + 1).forEach(index -> {
                try {
                    String name = rsmd.getColumnName(index);
                    String type = rsmd.getColumnTypeName(index);
                    Class<?> javaType = Class.forName(type);
                    JsonNode valueNode = mapper.valueToTree(rs.getObject(index, javaType));
                    rowNode.set(name, valueNode);
                } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });
            jsonArr.add(rowNode);
        }
        return jsonArr;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

the other way , here I have used ArrayList and Map, so its not  call json object row by row but after iteration of resultset finished :

```
 List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

  ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();  


      while(rs.next()){

              Map map = new HashMap();
              for (int i = 1; i <= rsMetaData.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                 String key = rsMetaData.getColumnName(i);

                  String value = null;

               if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.VARCHAR) {
                           value = rs.getString(key);
               } else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.BIGINT)                         
                             value = rs.getLong(key);
               }                  


                    map.put(key, value);
              }
              list.add(map);


    }


     json.put(list);
```