# resultset into JSON. How can I print the json Object?

Tags: java, json, object, resultset

I am referring to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6514876/779429) but I have slightly modified my approach..

This is the code that I have :

```
 public JSONArray generateJSON(ResultSet rs) {

        JSONArray respJSON = new JSONArray();

        try {
            java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            while (rs.next()) {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                for (int i = 1; i < numColumns + 1; i++) {

                    String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
                    if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.ARRAY) {
                        obj.put(columnName, rs.getArray(i));
                    } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.BIGINT) {
                        obj.put(columnName, rs.getInt(i));
                    } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN) {
                        obj.put(columnName, rs.getBoolean(i));
                    } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.BLOB) {
                        obj.put(columnName, rs.getBlob(i));
                    } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.DOUBLE) {
                        obj.put(columnName, rs.getDouble(i));
                    } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.FLOAT) {
                        obj.put(columnName, rs.getFloat(i));
                    } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.INTEGER) {
                        obj.put(columnName, rs.getInt(i));
                    } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR) {
                        obj.put(columnName, rs.getNString(i));
                    } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.VARCHAR) {
                        obj.put(columnName, rs.getString(i));
                    } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.TINYINT) {
                        obj.put(columnName, rs.getInt(i));
                    } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.SMALLINT) {
                        obj.put(columnName, rs.getInt(i));
                    } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.DATE) {
                        obj.put(columnName, rs.getDate(i));
                    } else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP) {
                        obj.put(columnName, rs.getTimestamp(i));
                    } else {
                        obj.put(columnName, rs.getObject(i));
                    }

                }
                respJSON.put(obj);
                //respJSON.add(obj);

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        respJSON.toString();

        return respJSON;

        System.out.print(respJSON.toString());
    }
```

My problem is that I can not print the json string to see it in the console ...

I have tried the respJSON.toString(); and it doesnt seem to work ..

Could you please help me ? ...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program cannot reach to the `print` statement as there is a `return` statement before that. If you had been using an IDE like `Netbeans` or `Eclipse`, that would have given you a clear warning.

Answer (score 4):

this is a simple typo. instead of this:

```
    respJSON.toString();
    return respJSON;
    System.out.print(respJSON.toString());
```

do this

```
    System.out.print(respJSON.toString());
    return respJSON;
```