# Java code for getting data from SQL server to MongoDB

Tags: java, sql-server, mongodb

I have been struggling with my Mongo-SQL code for a while and still need your help :)

I have a problem while transferring data from an SQL server database to MongoDB. My problem is that I can't do calculations like `AVERAGE()` or `SUM()` on my data since I saved them as string in MongoDB. I thought that the numbers would be integers since I got them from my SQL server database where they are stored as integers using the code below. I see now that I use `getString()` when getting the values. Is that why the numbers are strings in MongoDB? How can I get them as integers? I really want to be able to manipulate them as numbers! Also, some values in SQL server are datetime, so I will need a lot of 'if' statements and different 'get' methods to get all the types right in MongoDB. Does anyone have a good solution to this problem?

```
StringBuilder orderstatus = new StringBuilder();
orderstatus.append("SELECT * FROM dbo.fact_orderstatus");
PreparedStatement t = connect.prepareStatement(orderstatus.toString());  

DBCollection orderstat = db.getCollection("Orderstatus");

ResultSet v = t.executeQuery();
ResultSetMetaData rsm = t.getMetaData();
int column = rsm.getColumnCount();

while (v.next()) {
BasicDBObject orderObj = new BasicDBObject();
for(int x=1; x<column +1; x++){
String namn= rsm.getColumnName(x);

String custNum = (v.getString(x));
if (custNum != null && !custNum.trim().isEmpty()
&& custNum.length() != 0)
orderObj.append(namn, custNum);

}


orderstat.insert(orderObj)
```

Comment: I would expect that you have schema for the SQL table, right?  Can you just look at the type each column is and make appropriate gets based on that?

Comment: yes of course but then i have to get the columns one by one, and i have 10 tables with at least 40 columns in each. I would really like to solve this with some kind of loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize the getColumnType() method on your result set.

Since you're using SQL-server I would suggest reading this first:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378668.aspx

This SO question/answer is likely to be helpful too:
[Most efficient conversion of ResultSet to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514876/most-effecient-conversion-of-resultset-to-json)