# Working With Java to transform result of ResultSet, by which I do not know the number of columns in the query

Tags: java, json

I am starting my studies in Java. For this reason I am not very familiar with libraries and methods that exist Java. I would like to understand if there is any way of catching an object of type ResultSet, as the the return of a query made as follows:

```
The ResultSet rs_Tbl_CONTROL_SYNCHRONISM = 
con.query("Select * From DB_EGLISE.Tbl_CONTROL_synchronism;");
```

After obtaining ResultSet, is there any way to transform the output to JSON format? Is there a library, or some other method that will do this for me?

I noticed a few question similar to my however none of them will respond fully my doubts, must understand how to do in JAVA to transform the return of a ResultSET Object all to JSON, in response found on site, I noticed that it is necessary to inform each field returned, but do not know which fields will return to be a dynamic program, i.e. every time I will make a query. How should I proceed through this fault ? The GSON makes this ? And how do ?

Comment: I think this topic might help you : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514876/most-effecient-conversion-of-resultset-to-json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514876/most-effecient-conversion-of-resultset-to-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)firs set the class path to gson-2.1.jar

2)code to conver the ResultSet object information to JSON .

```
ResultSet rs_Tbl_CONTROL_SYNCHRONISM = con.query("Select * From DB_EGLISE.Tbl_CONTROL_synchronism;");

JsonObject jsonResponse = new JsonObject(); 
JsonArray data = new JsonArray();
while(rs_Tbl_CONTROL_SYNCHRONISM.next() ) {
JsonArray row = new JsonArray();
row.add(new JsonPrimitive(rs_Tbl_CONTROL_SYNCHRONISM.getString("columnName1")));
row.add(new JsonPrimitive(rs_Tbl_CONTROL_SYNCHRONISM.getString("columnName2")));
row.add(new JsonPrimitive(rs_Tbl_CONTROL_SYNCHRONISM.getString("columnName3")));

data.add(row);
}
jsonResponse.add("aaData", data);
```

Comment: How should I proceed with GSON when I do not know the number of columns returned the ResultSET ?

Comment: count columns ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();

Comment: To add this in my as would be ? The ResultSet rs_Tbl_PEOPLE = con.query("Select * From DB_EGLISE.Tbl_PEOPLE WHERE COD_Ident_IGREJ = '" + w_obj.getString("COD_Ident_IGREJ") +"' and COD_Ident_PERSONS = ''+ w_obj.getString("COD_Ident_persons") +"';");

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Gson adapter to convert ResultSet to Json

Example

```
List<ObjectX> objects= yourDao.list();
String jsonResult = new Gson().toJson(objects);
```

Comment: What is the way that I use GSON ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/riaqn/c0d73996dd187ff0d117