# Add to json array or json object directly from resultset loop

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

How to add all results from pojo to json object.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;  

while (srs.next()) {
    j obj = new pojo();
    ONObject json_o = new JSONObject();

    j.setFullname(srs.getString("full_name"));
    j.setEmailid(srs.getString("email_id"));

    // what to do here ?
}
```

Comment: what are `pojo`, `jo`, `srs` and `j`?

Comment: pojo is model class, srs is resultset

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6514876/4101906)