# JSON construction from mysql Query

Tags: java, mysql, json, oop, design-patterns

A Group by query gives this result from which I want to get the following JSON which produces a tree like chart:

Count   |  ApplicationStatus | Gender   |  Consent     |  Admitted

```
 71   Confirmed            Male     Submitted              No   
236   Confirmed            Male     Not Submitted          No  
  5   Confirmed            Male     Submitted              Yes 
782   Confirmed            Male     null                   No   
742   Confirmed            Male     null                   Yes  
  5   Confirmed            Male     Not Submitted          Yes  
235   Confirmed            Female   Submitted              No  
502   Confirmed            Female   null                   No  
563   Confirmed            Female   Not Submitted          No  
 17   Confirmed            Female   Submitted              Yes  
886   Confirmed            Female   null                   Yes  
 22   Confirmed            Female   Not Submitted          Yes  
 13   Unconfirmed          Male     Submitted              No  
594   Unconfirmed          Male     null                   No  
 81   Unconfirmed          Male     Not Submitted          No  
329   Unconfirmed          Male     null                   Yes  
 20   Unconfirmed          Female   Submitted              No    
428   Unconfirmed          Female   null                   No  
113   Unconfirmed          Female   Not Submitted          No  
  1   Unconfirmed          Female   Submitted              Yes  
284   Unconfirmed          Female   null                   Yes
```

Right now, I use parse the resultset (in JAVA) row by row and using nested if else statements, I generate the JSON. If I need to change something, it is really tricky to keep track of all the conditions and apply the desired changes correctly.

The JSON will be as follows:

{
Total:,
TotalStudents:,
Girls:,
Boys:,
Girls-Confirmed:,
Girls-UnConfirmed:,
Boys-Confirmed:,
Boys-Unconfirmed:,
Girls-Confirmed-Consentform(Submitted):,
Girls-UnConfirmed-Consentform(Submitted):,
Boys-Confirmed-Consentform(Submitted):,
Boys-Unconfirmed-Consentform(Submitted):,
ConsentForm(submitted)-Admitted:,
Girls-Confirmed-Admitted:(Without submitting consent form):,
Girls-UnConfirmed-Admitted:(Without submitting consent form):,
Boys-Confirmed-Admitted:(Without submitting consent form):,
Boys-Unconfirmed-Admitted:(Without submitting consent form):,
}

Just wanted to check if there is any other simpler approach to solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514876/most-efficient-conversion-of-resultset-to-json ?

Comment: Would help to show what "Conditions" you have.

Comment: @RC. Nope it is different scenario altogether.

Comment: @dbugger i have edited my question

Comment: Would be more useful to include the *code* that generates the JSON.