# How can I select datas to array in postgresql dbms?

Tags: java, sql, json, postgresql

Query result:

```
|  student_id  |  name  |  age  |  group  | 
---------------+--------+-------+----------  
| 1413001      | Ann    | 14    | Tennis  |
| 1413001      | Ann    | 14    | Choir   |
```

If I select records like this, I want to make them to JSON Object like

```
{student_id: "1413001", name: "Ann", Age: "14", group:["Tennis", "Choir"]}
```

How can I make them like that in Java or SQL?

Comment: [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19196092/5919568) should be useful .

Answer (score 1):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ce87473128c6922217f3699be9c8f906)

```
SELECT 
    row_to_json(s) 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        student_id, 
        name, 
        age, 
        json_agg("group") as "group"
    FROM students 
    GROUP BY student_id, name, age
) s
```

1. Group the "groups" into a json array with `json_agg`
2. The whole subquery rows can be converted into json objects with `row_to_json`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

---

Notice that "group" is a reserved word in Postgres. I recommend to rename this column.